# Repeated application of Schur complement

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, schur-complement

I want to understand why the following equivalency holds.

$$\begin{bmatrix}A - BD^{-1}B^{\top} & E\\ E^{\top} & C\end{bmatrix}\succ 0 \iff \begin{bmatrix}A & B & E \\ B^{\top} & D & 0\\ E^{\top} & 0& C\end{bmatrix}\succ 0$$
What is the justification for opening up the matrix $A - BD^{-1}B^{\top}$ inside the original matrix? How does the mechanics of this work if I want to do this repeatedly? I tried to prove this myself but I think there is some "fact" that I don't know yet that is blocking me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably $D$ is positive definite. The matrix on the left is just the Schur complement of $D$ in the $3\times3$ block matrix on the right. If you fail to see this, you may aid yourself by permuting the blocks first:
\begin{align}
&\pmatrix{A&B&E\\ B^T&D&0\\ E^T&0&C}\simeq\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}A&E&B\\ E^T&C&0\\ \hline B^T&0&D\end{array}\right),\\
&\pmatrix{A&E\\ E^T&C}-\pmatrix{B\\ 0}D^{-1}\pmatrix{B^T&0}
=\pmatrix{A-BD^{-1}B^T&E\\ E^T&C}.
\end{align}
Now, recall that the blockwise direct sum of $D$ and its Schur complement can be [obtained from the original matrix by matrix congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Background). Hence the $3\times3$ block matrix is positive definite iff both $D$ and its Schur complement are positive definite.